# another way to find the probability of poker dice outcomes?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If i want to find the probability of all five dice showing different numbers in one roll of poker dice, and getting one pair with the other three dice all different, how can i do this without using multinomial coefficients? I have tried to get the answer using this technique but i don't understand it, is there a way to do it purely with combinations (for example nCr)?

Thank you.

Comment: I have [a writeup about this](http://blog.plover.com/math/yahtzee.html) on my blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*All different*

$$\frac{{6\choose1}{5\choose1}{4\choose1}{3\choose1}{2\choose1}}{6^5}$$

*One pair*

$$\frac{{6\choose 1}{5\choose2}{5\choose 1}{4\choose 1}{3\choose 1}}{6^5}$$

The ${6\choose1}$ is to choose the pair, and the ${5\choose2}$ is to place the pair among the 5 dice

Comment: i understand how you choose the dice in the numerators but can you explain why you have to divide by 6^5?

Comment: Because each die can show any of 6 faces, so $6\times 6\times 6\times ... = 6^5$

Comment: thank you, this was an easy way of seeing it.

Comment: You're welcome !

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know what you mean by poker dice, so I'll assume it's just a set of 5 regular 6-sided dice.

To calculate the probability of all dice showing different numbers when rolled, number the dice from 1 to 5, and consider the possibilities for each die conditional on the previous dice.

The first die can show any number ($p_1=6/6$).

The second die can show any number except what's on the first die ($p_2=5/6$).

The third die can show any number except what's on the first and second dice ($p_3=4/6$).

And so on ($p_4=3/6$, $p_5=2/6$).

Multiply these together to get the result $P=(6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2) / (6^5)$.

You can follow a similar approach for the second part of your question.

Comment: for getting one pair and the other three dice all different values is it: (p1=6/6), (p2=1/6) since it has to be the same as the first, (p3=5/6), (p4=4/6), and (p5=3/6). P= (6 x 1 x 5 x 4 x 3) / (6^5)? i get 0.0463, but the correct answer is .463. why am i off by a tenth?

Comment: Because you're assuming the pair is composed of the first and second dice, when it could be composed of any two of the five dice. So you need to multiply by the number of ways of choosing 2 out of 5 dice, which is 5!/((5-2)!2!)=10.

Comment: thank you, it makes sense now

Comment: In that case, please mark one of the answers as correct.